# Does Spring Boot @RequestMapping match requests exactly?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot API which has endpoints that offer paging.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/most-popular", method = GET)
@Override
public List<RefinedAlbum> getMostPopularDefault() {
    return albumService.getMostPopular(0, 25);
}

@RequestMapping(path = "/most-popular?offset={offset}&limit={limit}", method = GET)
@Override
public List<RefinedAlbum> getMostPopular(@PathVariable("limit") int limit, @PathVariable("offset") int offset) {
    inputValidation(limit, offset);
    return albumService.getMostPopular(limit, offset);
}
```

But when I make a request to the service like:

```
http://localhost:5250/api/v1/albums/most-popular?offset=100&limit=125
```

The first function is called. My understanding was the exact matches should precede. Is that incorrect?

Comment: You're misunderstanding what path variables are. Path variables are /foo/{var1}/bar/{var2}, i.e. variables representings segments of the... path. What you have there is name a request **parameter**. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have after the `?` in the following URL cannot be bound using `@PathVariable` annotation:

```
http://localhost:5250/api/v1/albums/most-popular?offset=100&limit=125
```

Your path is just `http://localhost:5250/api/v1/albums/most-popular`, and the stuff after that consists of two request parameters, viz. `offset` and `limit`. You use `@RequestParam` annotation to bind request parameters to a method parameter in your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/most-popular", method = GET)
@Override
public List<RefinedAlbum> getMostPopular (@RequestParam("limit") int limit, 
   @RequestParam("offset") int offset) {
   inputValidation(limit, offset);
   return albumService.getMostPopular(limit, offset);
}
```

Comment: Thanks great help. Will read again through the documentation.